# Passing param to method from mustache template

Tags: java, mustache

I'm trying to pass a param to Java method from [mustache](https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java) template, and I tried looking at [Lambdas](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) but had no luck, in-fact when I set a breakpoint on the method it doesn't even get hit.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

java method

```
public List<Object> someMethod (String param) {
   //print it to console or do something with param ... 
}
```

mustache.html

```
<div id="someString" class="...">
    {{#someMethod "hello"}}
        ...
    {{/someMethod}}
 </div>
```

This results in an empty div when template gets processed. Can someone guid me on how to achieve this please or is this even possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use [handlebars](https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java).
In that case, you can use your template, as you have it now and passing parameters, in this way:

```
Handlebars handlebars = new Handlebars();
Template template = handlebars.compileInline("Hello {{this}}!");
System.out.println(template.apply("Handlebars.java"));
```

(You can compile inline like in the example, or pass a parameter with `handlebars.compile("mytemplate")`)

Output:

```
Hello Handlebars.java!
```

Is that what you were looking for? Hope it helps!

Comment: My project is already using Mustache extensively, and not sure if it would be appropriate at this point in time to switch to different library!

Comment: But .. how were you passing parameters to the mustache templates then?

Comment: If you would like to pass parameters, then I guess the smarter option would be to use one of this libraries. Bear in mind, that adding one of these dependencies won't break you current templates, but well.. I don't know which this are under your control, and which things are not.

Comment: Are you sure this won't break my current template?

Comment: Are u using maven? I think you can test it out, but I would say it won't break anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70398/discussion-between-simple-solution-and-facundofarias).

Comment: Unfortunately, because we're too ahead in the project...however, we comeup with a tedious approach which works for now.